# How to convert hexadecimal string to character with that code point?

Tags: python, string, hex, ascii, python-2.x

I have the string `x = '0x32'` and would like to turn it into `y = '\x32'`.
Note that `len(x) == 4` and `len(y) == 1`.

I've tried to use `z = x.replace("0", "\\")`, but that causes `z = '\\x32'` and `len(z) == 4`.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry about the convoluted title; better phrasing suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have to make it that hard: you can use `int(..,16)` to parse a hex string of the form `0x...`. Next you simply use `chr(..)` to convert that number into a character with that Unicode (and in case the code is less than 128 ASCII) code:

```
y = chr(int(x,16))
```

This results in:

```
>>> chr(int(x,16))
'2'
```

But `\x32` is equal to `'2'` (you can look it up in the ASCII table):

```
>>> chr(int(x,16)) == '\x32'
True
```

and:

```
>>> len(chr(int(x,16)))
1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
z = x[2:].decode('hex')
```

Comment: This is the most pythonic answer I've seen and it's actually pretty.
There is more to code than whether or not it works. That's the point of python.

Comment: @firstName Thanks, but sadly the `str.decode()` method is gone in Python 3. There, the much less elegant equivalent would be `bytes.fromhex(x[2:]).decode('utf-8')`.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to include code points like `'\x32'` inside a quoted string is a convenience for the programmer that only works in literal values inside the source code. Once you're manipulating strings in memory, that option is no longer available to you, but there are other ways of getting a character into a string based on its code point value.

Also note that `'\x32'` results in exactly the same string as `'2'`; it's just typed out differently.

Given a string containing a hexadecimal literal, you can convert it to its numeric value with `int(str,16)`. Once you have a numeric value, you can convert it to the character with that code point via `chr()`. So putting it all together:

```
x = '0x32'
print(chr(int(x,16)))
#=> 2
```