# python3 how to turn unicode codepoint into unicode char

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode

i know this type is asked alot but no answer was able to specifically help me with my problemsetup.

i have a list of ONLY Unicode codepoints so in this form:
304E
304F
...

No U+XXXX no '\XXXX' version.

Now i've tried to use stringmanipulation to recreate such strings
so i can simply print the corresponding unichar.
what i tried:

```py
x = u'\\u' + listString
```

```py
x = '\\u' + listString
```

```py
x = '\u' + listString
```

the first 2 when printed just give me a '\uXXXX' string, but no idea
how to make it print the char not that string.

the last one gives me this error:
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape

probably just something i dont get about unicode and stringmanipulation but i hope someone can help me out here.

Thanks in advance o/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert hexadecimal string to character with that code point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463940/how-to-convert-hexadecimal-string-to-character-with-that-code-point)

Comment: @Joe The linked answers indeed solve the OP's problem. However, this might not be obvious, as the linked question deals with input of the format `'oxNN'`, while here the input is `'NNNN'`.

Comment: @Nazzaroth, the answer by Mark Reed in the linked thread might help you understand why your attempts didn't work.

Comment: @lenz thank you, yeah just like Weeble below that did solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `chr` to get the character for a unicode code point:

```
>>> chr(0x304E)
'ぎ'
```

You can use `int` to convert a hexadecimal string to an integer:

```
>>> int('304E', 16)
12366
>>> chr(int('304E', 16))
'ぎ'
```

Comment: yup that does the trick. when you know the answer it seems so easy XD